# How to make a trigger "before commit" in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, triggers, transactions

Hello,

I have a table team and a table driver. Each team has 2 drivers. Insert a team with 0 or 1 driver is forbidden

**The below transaction is ok.**

```
INSERT INTO team (id, name, nationality) VALUES (1, 'Mercedes', 'German');
INSERT INTO driver (id, firstname, lastname, team_id) VALUES (10, 'Lewis', 'Hamilton', 1);
INSERT INTO driver (id, firstname, lastname, team_id) VALUES (20, 'Nico', 'Rosberg', 1);
COMMIT;
```

**The below transaction is NOT ok.**

```
INSERT INTO team (id, name, nationality) VALUES (1, 'Mercedes', 'German');
INSERT INTO driver (id, firstname, lastname, team_id) VALUES (10, 'Lewis', 'Hamilton', 1);
COMMIT;
```

I want to check this constraint with a trigger. But it doesn't exist a trigger BEFORE COMMIT. **How to implement the constraint which require 2 drivers per team ?** In other words, I just want to check if the transaction is ok or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by restructuring your data.  Instead of having the drivers refer to the team, have the team refer to the drivers:

```
create table team (
    . . . 
    driver1 int not null,
    driver2 int not null,
    . . .
    foreign key (driver1) references driver(id),
    foreign key (driver2) references driver(id),
    check (driver1 <> driver2)
);
```

Then the data structure automatically enforces this constraint, because you have to have the two values populated that are valid drivers and not equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I chose the tables team and drivers only for the understanding of the problem. I want to check the minimum cardinality in the model. In other words, the team could have 3, 4, 5... drivers, but a minimum of 2 drivers. Furthermore, each driver belongs to a team. In your reply, we can't be sure that each driver belongs to a team (a driver could be in the database without team).

A trigger and a procedure must be used to check this constraint. I want to check the transaction only before committing. However, I don't know how to trigger a procedure not after each row, but only before committing.